# ruby-odbc slow connect times for DB2 ODBC driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, db2, odbc

Every time the code is executed, it takes 30 seconds each time for `ODBC.connect` to establish a connection to the data source.

When running the same sql statement via `isql -v mustship` it takes .01 seconds to execute and finish so I know its something on this server or maybe I'm doing something wrong with my actions below? I read the ruby-odbc docs pretty carefully and didn't see anything surround this.

```
class MustshipsController < ApplicationController
require 'odbc'

def index
  mustshiptl = ODBC.connect("mustship", '', '')
  sql = "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM MUSTSHIPTL"
  stmt = mustshiptl.run(sql)

  # code execution here

  stmt.drop
end
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

If you use `CurrentSchema=libraryname` in your db2cli.ini file for IBM DB2 data sources the execution will be delayed while it sets the access path in DB2 to just this library. Removing this setting brought me back to milliseconds of execution time. Then you just need to define the library name for each table in sql call.

Hope this helps in case somebody runs into this in the future. Very frustrating.